Landau Notation Problem
I have this function
$$ K_{n} = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^n}dt$$ $$ \text{Let }t\geq1,t^2+1\geq1+t\Leftrightarrow\frac{1}{1+t^2}\leq\frac{1}{1+t} \text{ and for } n \in {\mathbb{N^{*}}} : \frac{1}{(1+t^2)^{n}}\leq\frac{1}{(1+t)^{n}} \\ \text{ We got } K_n=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^n}dt\leq\frac{1}{n-1}\times\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$
I need to prove that $$K_n=O(\frac{1}{n2^{n}})$$ I would like to have a detailed justification please or hint on how I can find the answer. My definition of O notation is that let's assume that $a_n, b_n, m_n$ positives sequences such that $m_n$ is bounded. We says that $a_n=O(b_n) \Leftrightarrow \exists N, \forall n\geq N, a_n\leq b_nM_n $.

Hint: note that you need to show that $C_1 \dfrac{1}{2^n n}\le K_n \le C_2 \dfrac{1}{2^n n}$. Note that one of the bounds is ready and the other bound can be obtained by estimating $1 + t^2 \le 2 t^2 $

Actualy I didn't find the answer using your hint but I still find something,  since $\frac{1}{n-1}~\frac{1}{n}$ we can assume that $\frac{1}{n-1}=O(\frac{1}{n})$ and since $\frac{2^n}{2^{n-1}} = 2$ we have $\frac{1}{2^(n-1)}=O(\frac{1}{2^n})$. So we have $\frac{1}{(n-1)2^{n-1}}=O(\frac{1}{n2^{n}})$ so we can assume that $K_n=O(\frac{1}{n2^{n}})$

For the lower bound, consider
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^n}
{
=
\int_1^2 \frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^n}
+
\int_2^\infty \frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^n}
\\\ge
\int_1^2 \frac{t/2dt}{(1+t^2)^n}
=
\frac{1}{4}\int_1^4 \frac{dt}{(1+t)^n}
\\=
\frac{1}{4n-4}\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-\frac{1}{5^{n-1}}\right).
}
$$
